# How to determine why a flush error occurs?

Tags: iis

We have an ISAPI module and filter that inspects and modifies responses.  We have this scenario where Firefox with HTTP2 enabled sends a request that fails within IIS, and a second request is immediately re-introduced into the pipeline (perhaps resent from the Firefox client).  The two requests are very similar except the first one had TE: trailer header and connection:close.  When looking at the Failed Request Trace, we see that the flush on the first request fails with 'the parameter is incorrect' (below).  Is there a way to track down more information on why the flush failed?  I tried to track it down within the managed pipeline but wasn't able to - it seems it may be occurring within native code, or maybe a communication error back to the client(?).  If Firefox has HTTP2 disabled, the flush error doesn't occur.  If we don't have the ISAPI module and filter, the first request succeeds.

````
0 ms

Verbose
GENERAL_RESPONSE_ENTITY_BUFFER 

Buffer
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Length: 192
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://SERVER-NAME/VDIR/PATH/FILE.aspx?url=https%3a%2f%2fSERVER-NAME%2fVDIR
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
request-id: b8945a72-543a-4474-9837-9420b3176c5b
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-X-Server: SERVER-NAME

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://SERVER-NAME/VDIR/PATH/FILE.aspx?url=https%3a%2f%2fSERVER-NAME%2fVDIR">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

0 ms

Informational
GENERAL_FLUSH_RESPONSE_END 

BytesSent
0 

ErrorCode
The parameter is incorrect.
 (0x80070057) 

0 ms
GENERAL_REQUEST_END 


BytesSent
0 

BytesReceived
733 

HttpStatus
302 

HttpSubStatus
0 ```
````

Comment: please check the event viewer application log for more detail. if possible could you please provide the sample code?

Comment: Jalpa, thanks for responding.  Unfortunately the code is too complex, and it is both an ISAPI Filter and an ISAPI Module (written in c++ managed code).  I was not expecting to see something in the Event Viewer - unless there is a specialized event log that I need to be looking at (?).  I will repro and take a look if anything is logged in the standard Application / Security / System event logs.  I'm hoping someone can tell me what log to enable to see details on why the Flush failed, to show more details than what is in the Failed Request Trace log above.

Comment: Jalpa, I reproduced the error, but there aren't any corresponding event logs in Application / Security / System.

Comment: Just to clarify, we are not calling a Flush on a buffer, otherwise I would have stepped into the Microsoft code (at least the managed pipeline part)... it seems this occurs after the pipeline finished, and I suspect no longer in the managed code part.